# setTimeout not working although works in another similar script

Tags: javascript, jquery

After inserting some text into a div I call `setTimeout()` with a redirect which doesnt work, I'm using an almost identical script I use in another project which does work, I do not undrstand why?

**script that works**

```
$.getJSON("http://newberylodge.co.uk/webapp/includes/login1.php",{username:childsname,password:password},function(json)   {

    if(json.result === "success") {

        $("#add_err").html( "Welcome "+childsname+"!");

        setTimeout(function(){
              window.location= "menu.html"; 
        },2000);                          

    }else{
        $("#add_err").html(json.message);
    }
});
    }
```

**script that isnt working**

```
$.post("includes/addVolunteer.inc.php",{volunteerName:volunteerName,volunteerCity:volunteerCity, volunteerCounty:volunteerCounty,volunteerService:volunteerService,volunteerEmail:volunteerEmail},function(json)   {

    if(json.result === "success") {

        $("#volunteerReport").html(json.message);

                setTimeout(function(){
              window.location= "view.htm"; 
        },2000); 


    }else{
        $("#volunteerReport").html(json.message);
    }
});
    }
```

I have checked for errors in console and there are none being shown

Comment: Does `json.result` = `success` in the data that's returned from `addVolunteer.inc.php`?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes the text is added to the div that is returned from the json message on success, then the setTimeout should be called but for some reason isn't being called, there are no errors being shown in console

Comment: you check console log? any error in log? you try debug?

Comment: inspect element and check in console for any error

Comment: @Akash I have checked in console and there is no error reported, you can see this in action at http://ridersinthesky.co.uk/rits_developement/volunteer.php and am happy if you add something to see the process as this is a prototype at the moment

Comment: you can try my answer. i think it's helpful to you.. it's your mistake in your response.. In response you return `0` instead of `result` as a `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this

```
$.post("includes/addVolunteer.inc.php",{volunteerName:volunteerName,volunteerCity:volunteerCity, volunteerCounty:volunteerCounty,volunteerService:volunteerService,volunteerEmail:volunteerEmail},function(json)   {

    if(json[0] === "success") {

        $("#volunteerReport").html(json.message);

        setTimeout(function(){
            window.location= "view.htm"; 
        },2000); 


    }else{
        $("#volunteerReport").html(json.message);
    }
});
    }
```

I'm not sure but it's helpful to you.

Comment: That worked, can you explain how that addition made a difference to the script I used please

Comment: In your post request, you return two values, one is result and second is message. but in your code by mistake you are return `0` instead of `result` as a key name. Please check your code.

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation, Its strange my code worked on a different project but not this one, I am grateful for your help